# Create new Dataframe with empty/null field values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am creating a new Dataframe from an existing dataframe, but need to add new column ("field1" in below code) in this new DF. How do I do so? Working sample code example will be appreciated.

```
val edwDf = omniDataFrame 
  .withColumn("field1", callUDF((value: String) => None)) 
  .withColumn("field2",
    callUdf("devicetypeUDF", (omniDataFrame.col("some_field_in_old_df")))) 

edwDf
  .select("field1", "field2")
  .save("odsoutdatafldr", "com.databricks.spark.csv");
```

Answer (score 110):

It is possible to use `lit(null)`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit, udf}

case class Record(foo: Int, bar: String)
val df = Seq(Record(1, "foo"), Record(2, "bar")).toDF

val dfWithFoobar = df.withColumn("foobar", lit(null: String))
```

One problem here is that the column type is `null`:

```scala
scala> dfWithFoobar.printSchema
root
 |-- foo: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- bar: string (nullable = true)
 |-- foobar: null (nullable = true)
```

and it is not retained by the `csv` writer. If it is a hard requirement you can cast column to the specific type (lets say String), with either `DataType`

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType

df.withColumn("foobar", lit(null).cast(StringType))
```

or string description

```scala
df.withColumn("foobar", lit(null).cast("string"))
```

or use an UDF like this:

```scala
val getNull = udf(() => None: Option[String]) // Or some other type

df.withColumn("foobar", getNull()).printSchema
root
 |-- foo: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- bar: string (nullable = true)
 |-- foobar: string (nullable = true)
```

A Python equivalent can be found here: [Add an empty column to spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33038686/6910411)

Comment: @zero323, thanks for sharing this, very helpful. See my edits for support other types.

Comment: @DmitriySelivanov Thank you for your helpful edit. I gave up the idea of using `Option` after some failed experiments with literals a while ago :)

Comment: Is it possible to output a null Struct, so it can be saved to Parquet with null value but struct type? val getNull = udf(() => None: Option[StructType]) didn't work for me in 2.4

Answer (score 20):

Just to extend the perfect answer provided by @zero323, here's a solution which can be used starting from Spark 2.2.0.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.typedLit

df.withColumn("foobar", typedLit[Option[String]](None)).printSchema
root
 |-- foo: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- bar: string (nullable = true)
 |-- foobar: string (nullable = true)
```

It's similar to the 3rd solution, but without using any UDF.