# Spark SQL average non zero values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In Scala Spark

```
val df = sc.parallelize(0 to 3).toDF("x")
df.registerTempTable("df")

sqlContext.sql("select * from df").show
+---+
|  x|
+---+
|  0|
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
+---+
```

and would like to average non zero values only. Tried this (does not work),

```
sqlContext.sql("select avg(nullif(x,0)) from df").show
```

What is a simple and efficient way to average non zero values ?

Comment: I guess NULLIF is not supported in Spark SQL
"org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: undefined function NULLIF;"

Comment: Try to check this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357164/sparksql-how-to-deal-with-null-values-in-user-defined-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try :

```
sqlContext.sql(
  "select avg(case when id=0 then null else id end), avg(id) from df"
).show
```

Answer (score 1):

To select non-zero values, have a where clause like

```
 sqlContext.sql("select avg(x) from df where x >0").show
```

The response that I get is

```
+---+
|_c0|
+---+
|2.0|
+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this without sql statement:

**Java:**

```
df.filter(df.col("x").gt(0).or(df.col("x").lt(0))) // x > 0 or x < 0
  .select(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.avg("x")) // avg(x)
  .show();
```

**Scala:**

```
df.filter(df("x")>0 || df("x")<0)
  .select(avg("x"))
  .show
```