# Spark UDF Null handling

Tags: scala, apache-spark, udf

I'm struggeling handling null values in a UDF which operates on dataframe (which originates from a hive table) consisting of a struct of floats:

The dataframe (`points`) has the following schema:

```
root
 |-- point: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- x: float (nullable = true)
 |    |-- y: float (nullable = true)
```

For example, I want to calculate the sum of x and y. Note that I do not "handle" null values in the following examples, but I want to be able to check in my udf whether `point`,`x` or `y` are `null`.

First approach:

```
val sum = udf((x:Float,y:Float) => x+y)

points.withColumn("sum",sum($"point.x",$"point.y"))
```

This does not work if the `struct` point is `null`, in this case the udf is never evaluated (the code in the udf is never executed!), the result is null. Also, I cannot check `x` or `y` for being null as `Floats` cannot be null in scala.

Second approach:

```
val sum = udf((pt:Row) => pt.getFloat(0)+pt.getFloat(1))
points.withColumn("sum",sum($"point"))
```

Which this approach, I can check `pt` for null in my udf, but I'm nut able to check `x` and `y` because `Floats` cannot be null. I get a `NullPointerException` in this case.

How can I write an udf win which I can check the struct and x and y for being null?

I'm using spark 1.6.1

Update:
In contrast to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357164/sparksql-how-to-deal-with-null-values-in-user-defined-function), I'm dealing with floats and not with strings (strings can be null in scala, floats not)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Row.isNullAt(i)` to check if `i`th field is null. In your case, you should write your udf as,

```
sum = udf((point: Row) => point.match {
  case p if (p.isNullAt(0) && p.isNullAt(0)) => 0f
  case p if p.isNullAt(0) => p.getFloat(1)
  case p if p.isNullAt(1) => p.getFloat(0)
  case p => p.getFloat(0) + p.getFloat(1)
})
```