# How to filter nullable Array-Elements in Spark 1.6 UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Consider the following DataFrame

```
root
 |-- values: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
```

with content:

```
+-----------+
|     values|
+-----------+
|[1.0, null]|
+-----------+
```

Now I want to pass thie `value` column to an UDF:

```
val inspect = udf((data:Seq[Double]) => {
  data.foreach(println)
  println()
  data.foreach(d => println(d))
  println()
  data.foreach(d => println(d==null))
  ""
})

df.withColumn("dummy",inspect($"values"))
```

I'm really confused from the output of the above `println` statements:

```
1.0
null

1.0
0.0

false
false
```

My questions:

1. Why is `foreach(println)` not giving the same output as `foreach(d=>println(d))`?
2. How can the `Double` be null in the first println-statement, I thought scala's `Double` cannot be null?
3. How can I filter null values in my `Seq` other han filtering `0.0` which isnt really safe? Should I use `Seq[java.lang.Double]` as type for my input in the UDF and then filter nulls? (this works, but I'm unsure if that is the way to go)

Note that I'm aware of [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357164/sparksql-how-to-deal-with-null-values-in-user-defined-function), but my question is specific to array-type columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is foreach(println) not giving the same output as foreach(d=>println(d))?

In the context where `Any` is expected data cast is skipped completely. This is explained in detail in [If an Int can't be null, what does null.asInstanceOf[Int] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10749010/691041)

> How can the Double be null in the first println-statement, I thought scala's Double cannot be null?

Internal binary representation doesn't use Scala types at all. Once array data is decoded it is represented as an `Array[Any]` and elements are coerced to a declared type with simple `asInstanceOf`.

> Should I use Seq[java.lang.Double] as type for my input in the UDF and then filter nulls?

In general if values are nullable then you should use external type which is nullable as well or `Option`. Unfortunately only the first option is applicable for UDFs.