# How to deal with Spark UDF input/output of primitive nullable type

Tags: sql, apache-spark, null, udf

The issues:

1) Spark doesn't call UDF if input is column of primitive type that contains `null`:

```
inputDF.show()

+-----+
|  x  |
+-----+
| null|
|  1.0|
+-----+

inputDF
  .withColumn("y",
     udf { (x: Double) => 2.0 }.apply($"x") // will not be invoked if $"x" == null
  )
  .show()

+-----+-----+
|  x  |  y  |
+-----+-----+
| null| null|
|  1.0|  2.0|
+-----+-----+
```

2) Can't produce `null` from UDF as a column of primitive type:

`udf { (x: String) => null: Double } // compile error`

Answer (score 12):

Accordingly to [the docs](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/9f523d3192c71a728fd8a2a64f52bbc337f2f026/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/ScalaUDF.scala#L28):

> Note that if you use primitive parameters, you are not able to check
>   if it is null or not, and the UDF will return null for you if the
>   primitive input is null. **Use boxed type or [[Option]] if you wanna do
>   the null-handling yourself.**

So, the easiest solution is just to use
boxed types if your UDF input is nullable column of primitive type
OR/AND you need to output null from UDF as a column of primitive type:

```
inputDF
  .withColumn("y",
     udf { (x: java.lang.Double) => 
       (if (x == null) 1 else null): java.lang.Integer
     }.apply($"x")
  )
  .show()

+-----+-----+
|  x  |  y  |
+-----+-----+
| null| null|
|  1.0|  2.0|
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Note that the docs you cited are a bit misleading: Although `Option` can be used to return "nullable" primitives, `Option` cannot be used as input for the UDF (at least in Spark 1.6, not sure about 2.0)

Comment: @RaphaelRoth Agree, they had to mention that Option[] is useful only to return nullable values.

Answer (score 2):

I would also use Artur's solution, but there is also another way without using javas wrapper classes by using `struct`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.struct
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

inputDF
  .withColumn("y",
     udf { (r: Row) => 
       if (r.isNullAt(0)) Some(1) else None
     }.apply(struct($"x"))
  )
  .show()
```

Comment: That's nice too!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution provided at [SparkSQL: How to deal with null values in user defined function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357164/sparksql-how-to-deal-with-null-values-in-user-defined-function) by [@zero323](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1560062/zero323), an alternative way to achieve the requested result is:

```
import scala.util.Try
val udfHandlingNulls udf((x: Double) => Try(2.0).toOption)
inputDF.withColumn("y", udfHandlingNulls($"x")).show()
```