# Add an empty column to Spark DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

As mentioned in [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483498/append-a-column-to-data-frame-in-apache-spark-1-3) [other locations](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Append-column-to-Data-Frame-or-RDD-td22385.html) on the web, adding a new column to an existing DataFrame is not straightforward. Unfortunately it is important to have this functionality (even though it is inefficient in a distributed environment) especially when trying to concatenate two `DataFrame`s using `unionAll`.

What is the most elegant workaround for adding a `null` column to a `DataFrame` to facilitate a `unionAll`?

My version goes like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import UserDefinedFunction
to_none = UserDefinedFunction(lambda x: None, StringType())
new_df = old_df.withColumn('new_column', to_none(df_old['any_col_from_old']))
```

Answer (score 196, accepted):

All you need here is importing `StringType` and using `lit` and `cast`:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

new_df = old_df.withColumn('new_column', lit(None).cast(StringType()))
```

A full example:

```
df = sc.parallelize([row(1, "2"), row(2, "3")]).toDF()
df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- foo: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- bar: string (nullable = true)

new_df = df.withColumn('new_column', lit(None).cast(StringType()))

new_df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- foo: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- bar: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- new_column: string (nullable = true)

new_df.show()
# +---+---+----------+
# |foo|bar|new_column|
# +---+---+----------+
# |  1|  2|      null|
# |  2|  3|      null|
# +---+---+----------+
```

A Scala equivalent can be found here: [Create new Dataframe with empty/null field values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32067467/1560062)

Comment: How to do this conditionally, if the column does not exist in the first place? I am trying to use UDF and pass the DF to it and then doing `new_column not in df.columns` check, but can't make it to work.

Comment: I looked at it too, but I was still not able to incorporate that conditionally into a `withColumn('blah', where(has_column(df['blah']) == False)....` kind of construct. Must be missing some syntactical construct. I want to add a column with Nulls, if it does not exist. This answer does former, the other one checks latter.

Comment: @Gopala `df if has_column(df) else df.withColumn(....)` - nothing Spark specific.

Comment: Darn....I get really mixed up with when python syntax works, and when it does not. For example, you can't have conditional code within the `withColumn` and have to use UDFs. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

I would cast lit(None) to NullType instead of StringType. So that if we ever have to filter out not null rows on that column...it can be easily done as follows

```
df = sc.parallelize([Row(1, "2"), Row(2, "3")]).toDF()

new_df = df.withColumn('new_column', lit(None).cast(NullType()))

new_df.printSchema() 

df_null = new_df.filter(col("new_column").isNull()).show()
df_non_null = new_df.filter(col("new_column").isNotNull()).show()
```

Also be careful about not using lit("None")(with quotes) if you are casting to StringType since it would fail for searching for records with filter condition .isNull() on col("new_column").

Comment: Error: `Parquet data source does not support null data type.;`. `StringType()` worked.

Comment: This could be a very bad idea depending on your usecase, as it casts the column as a Void type, and thus nothing can be inserted other than null if you write this out to some kind of storage, e.g. delta format.

Answer (score 6):

The option without `import StringType`

```
df = df.withColumn('foo', F.lit(None).cast('string'))
```

Full example:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.range(1, 3).toDF('c')

df = df.withColumn('foo', F.lit(None).cast('string'))

df.printSchema()
#     root
#      |-- c: long (nullable = false)
#      |-- foo: string (nullable = true)

df.show()
#     +---+----+
#     |  c| foo|
#     +---+----+
#     |  1|null|
#     |  2|null|
#     +---+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1.selectExpr("school","null as col1").show()
```

output：

```
+--------------------+----+
|              school|col1|
+--------------------+----+
|Shanghai Jiao Ton...|null|
|   Peking University|null|
|Shanghai Jiao Ton...|null|
|    Fudan University|null|
|    Fudan University|null|
| Tsinghua University|null|
|Shanghai Jiao Ton...|null|
| Tsinghua University|null|
| Tsinghua University|null|
|   Peking University|null|
```

or in pyspark 2.2+

```
df1.pandas_api().assign(new_column=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Pyspark 2.3 you can also use the function `unionByName` with the option `allowMissingColumns=True` for your original purpose of unioning two dataframes with partly different columns.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unionByName.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use this?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
df.withColumn("column_name", lit("")).show()
```

Comment: This results in an "empty string" (a string of length 0). This is not the same as null. In fact, quite often, when preparing data for analysis, empty strings are converted into nulls.