# Add empty column to dataframe in Spark with python

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a dataframe that I want to make a `unionAll` with another dataframe. The problem is that the second dataframe has three more columns than the first one. Is there a way for me to add three columns with only empty cells in my first dataframe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add an empty column to spark DataFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33038686/add-an-empty-column-to-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.withColumn('NewColumn', lit(None).cast(StringType()))
```

Comment: If I do df.fillna(0) after this statement. It doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help

To add string type column:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

df.withColumn("COL_NAME", lit(None).cast(StringType()))
```

To Add integer type

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

df.withColumn("COL_NAME", lit(0).cast(IntegerType()))
```

Comment: Just an observation: in your second example, the imported type does not match with the converted type used.

Answer (score 1):

use `withColumn` object of spark-dataframe
`DF.withColumn("NewCol","Value")`

Comment: How do I get the value to be a blanc column?

Comment: got it to work with .withColumn('NewCol', lit(None).cast(StringType()))

Comment: I could not understand you.