# Adding empty columns to dataframe with empty values (by type) pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following list:

```
columns = [('url','string'),('count','bigint'),('isindex','boolean')]
```

I want to add this columns to my df with empty values:

```
for column in columns:
df = df.withColumn(column[0], f.lit(?).cast(?))
```

I am not sure what I need to put in the lit function and in the cast in order to have the suitable empty value for each type

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add an empty column to Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33038686/add-an-empty-column-to-spark-dataframe)

Comment: No because the answer is for specific type

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66267256/14165730) is more similar to what you want to do