# How to add columns to df with StructField Array?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes, and I want to add to the first of them all the columns that are in the second, but not in the first. I got an array of StructField columns that I want to add to the dataframe, and fill with nulls.

That's the best I've come up with:

```
private def addColumns(df: DataFrame, columnsToAdd: Array[StructField]): DataFrame = {
    val spark = df.sparkSession
    val schema = new StructType(df.schema.toArray ++ columnsToAdd)
    spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, schema)
}
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: As it turned out, my method does not work, when calling any action, spark crashes with java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution that I gave in the question unfortunately does not work. Crashes with the error **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**. As I understand it, the fact is that even though I added columns to the **schema**, they were not added to the **dataframe**, spark is trying to access the next data frame field, which is in the **schema**, but not in the real data.

I wrote such a variant, it uses recursion and does what I want. Although of course I would like to abandon the use of **null**, and somehow replace it with **None**.

```
@tailrec
private def addColumns(df: DataFrame, columnsToAdd: Array[StructField], indx: Int): DataFrame = {
    if(columnsToAdd.length == indx || columnsToAdd.isEmpty) df
    else {
        val dfWithColumn = df.withColumn(columnsToAdd(indx).name, lit(null).cast(columnsToAdd(indx).dataType))
        addColumns(dfWithColumn, columnsToAdd, indx + 1)
    }
}
```

Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33038686/add-an-empty-column-to-spark-dataframe) helped a lot.