# How can I replace numbers by nulls in a DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

It might be strange, but I was wondering how to replace any number of a whole `DataFrame`'s `Column` for `null` using `Scala`.

Imagine I have a nullable `DoubleType` column named `col`. There, I want to replace all numbers different to (1.0 ~ 10.0) by a `null`.

I tried unsatisfactorily the next code.

```
val xf = df.na.replace("col", Map(0.0 -> null.asInstanceOf[Double]).toMap)
```

But, as you realize in `Scala` when you convert a `null` into a `Double` it becomes represented as a `0.0`, and this is not what I want. Besides, I can't realize any way to do it with a range of values. Therefore, I am thinking if there is any way to achieve this?

Comment: Is `na.replace` a hard requirement here?

Comment: @zero323 No there is no need, I am just pulling out my hairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `when` clause instead?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.when

val df = sc.parallelize(
  (1L, 0.0) :: (2L, 3.6) :: (3L, 12.0) :: (4L, 5.0) ::  Nil
).toDF("id", "val")

df.withColumn("val", when($"val".between(1.0, 10.0), $"val")).show

// +---+----+
// | id| val|
// +---+----+
// |  1|null|
// |  2| 3.6|
// |  3|null|
// |  4| 5.0|
// +---+----+
```

Any value which doesn't satisfy the predicate (here `val BETWEEN 1.0 AND 10.0`) will be replaced with `NULL`.

See also [Create new Dataframe with empty/null field values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32067467/1560062)

Comment: Just to leave it as an informative comment for the future. How would you do if you want to replace others except....? :)

Comment: You can replace `$"val".between(1.0, 10.0)` with some other logical expression (`isIn`, `not(isIn)` and so on).

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto Can I take a moment of you time?

Comment: If so lets switch to chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103319/discussion-between-alberto-bonsanto-and-zero323