# Spark: Return empty column if column does not exist in dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

As shown in the below code, I am reading a JSON file into a dataframe and then selecting some fields from that dataframe into another one.

```
df_record = spark.read.json("path/to/file.JSON",multiLine=True)

df_basicInfo = df_record.select(col("key1").alias("ID"), \
                                col("key2").alias("Status"), \
                                col("key3.ResponseType").alias("ResponseType"), \
                                col("key3.someIndicator").alias("SomeIndicator") \
                                )
```

Issue is that some times, the JSON file does not have some of the keys that I try to fetch - like `ResponseType`. So it ends up throwing errors like:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No such struct field ResponseType
```

How can I get around this issue without forcing a schema at the time of read? is it possible to make it return a NULL under that column when it is not available?

[how do I detect if a spark dataframe has a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904136) Does mention how to detect if a column is available in a dataframe. This question, however, is about how to use that function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I detect if a spark dataframe has a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904136/how-do-i-detect-if-a-spark-dataframe-has-a-column)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using `has_column` function define [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36332079) by [zero323](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1560062/zero323) and [general guidelines about adding empty columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32067467) either

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, col, when
from pyspark.sql.types import *

if has_column(df_record, "key3.ResponseType"):
    df_basicInfo = df_record.withColumn("ResponseType", col("key3.ResponseType"))
else:
    # Adjust types according to your needs
    df_basicInfo = df_record.withColumn("ResponseType", lit(None).cast("string"))
```

Adjust types according to your requirements, and repeat process for the remaining columns.

Alternatively define a schema that covers all desired types:

```py
schema = StructType([
    StructField("key1", StringType()),
    StructField("key2", StringType()),
    StructField("key2", StructType([
        StructField("ResponseType", StringType()),
        StructField("someIndicator", StringType()),
    ]))
])

df_record = spark.read.schema(schema).json("path/to/file.JSON",multiLine=True)
```

(once again adjust the types), and use your current code.

Comment: Is there any SparkSQL version?

Comment: case when otherwise is failing if there is no column.

Comment: I tried this but it always evaluates `col("key3.ResponseType")` and if the column doesn't exists, it will throw an error.

Comment: The second option requires the column to exist in order to evaluate when.  So as @Hello.World said this throws an error if the column does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Spark is missing a simple function: `struct_has(STRUCT, PATH)` or `struct_get(STRUCT, PATH, DEFAULT)` where `PATH`use dot notation.

So I wrote a very simple UDF:

From https://gist.github.com/ebuildy/3c9b2663d47f7b65fbc12cfb469ae19c:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

spark.udf.register("struct_def", (root:GenericRowWithSchema, path: String, defaultValue: String) => {

    var fields = path.split("\\.")
    var buffer:Row = root
    val lastItem = fields.last

    fields = fields.dropRight(1)

    fields.foreach( (field:String) => {
        if (buffer != null) {
            if (buffer.schema.fieldNames.contains(field)) {
                buffer = buffer.getStruct(buffer.fieldIndex(field))
            } else {
                buffer = null
            }
        }
    })

    if (buffer == null) {
        defaultValue
    } else {
        buffer.getString(buffer.fieldIndex(lastItem))
    }
})
```

This let you query like this:

```
SELECT struct_get(MY_COL, "foo.bar", "no") FROM DATA
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, i used a similar approach as Thomas.
My user defined function code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

spark.udf.register("tryGet", (root:GenericRowWithSchema, fieldName: String) => {
    var buffer:Row = root

    if (buffer != null) {
      if (buffer.schema.fieldNames.contains(fieldName)) {
         buffer.getString(buffer.fieldIndex(fieldName))
      } else {
        null
      }
    }
    else {
      null
    }
})
```

and then my Query:

```
%sql

SELECT
  Id,
  Created,
  Payload.Type,
  tryGet(Payload, "Error") as Error,
FROM dataWithJson
WHERE Payload.Type = 'Action'
```

Comment: i tried and getting org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(DataFrameConverter$$$Lambda$2744/0x000000080192ef48: (string, string) => string)

Answer (score 1):

So I tried using the accepted answer, however I found that if the column `key3.ResponseType` doesn't exist, it will fail.

You can do something like this -

```
def hasColumn(df: DataFrame, path: String) = 
  if (Try(df(path)).isSuccess == true) {
      df(path)
  }
  else {
      lit(null) 
  }
```

Here you evaluate in function if column exists, and if it doesn't it just returns a NULL column.

You can now use this like -

```
df_basicInfo = df_record.withColumn("ResponseType", hasColumn(df_record, "key3.ResponseType"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw many confusing answers, so I hope this helps in `Pyspark`, here is how you do it! Create a function to check on the columns and keep checking each column to see if it exists, if not replace it with `None` or a relevant datatype value.

```
from pyspark.sql.utils import AnalysisException
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, col, when


def has_column(df, col):
    try:
        df[col]
        return True
    except AnalysisException:
        return False
```

Now, as mentioned in the question

```
df_record = spark.read.json("path/to/file.JSON",multiLine=True)
df_new = df_record

if has_column(df_new, "data.col1"):
    df_new = df_new.withColumn("col_1", col("data.col1"))
else:
    df_new = df_new.withColumn("col_1", lit(None).cast("string")) 


if has_column(df_new, "log.id"):
    df_new = df_loader.withColumn("log_id", col("log.id").cast("bigint"))
else:
    df_new = df_new.withColumn("log_id", lit(None).cast("bigint")) 

.....
```

and so on, you make relevant changes to the `dataframe` till you finally see all the fields you want to populate in `df_new`. Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is casting your struct type column to string and using the [get_json_object](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.get_json_object.html?highlight=get_json_object#pyspark.sql.functions.get_json_object) function. It can handle unknown fields.
eg:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import get_json_object
df_record.select(get_json_object(df_record.key3.cast("string"),'$. ResponseType').alias('ResponseType'))
```

The output will always be string. The string 'null' will be the column value where the required field is not found