# Dataframe withColumn and null

Tags: apache-spark

I have a simple code that uses `DataFrame.withColumn`

```
  test("SparkSQLTest") {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("SparkSQLTest").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    var df = spark.createDataset(
      Seq(
        ("1", "2"),
        ("3", "4")
      )
    ).toDF("a", "b")
    df = df.withColumn("c", functions.lit(null.asInstanceOf[String]).as[String])
    df.printSchema()
    df.show(truncate = false)
  }
```

The output schema is:

```
root
 |-- a: string (nullable = true, metadata = {})
 |-- b: string (nullable = true, metadata = {})
 |-- c: null (nullable = true, metadata = {})
```

`c` column's type is null, i thought it was string. If it was null, then I can't write to csv, as null data type is not supported.

I would ask how to make c's type correct.

Comment: try it   .withColumn("c", lit(null).cast("string"))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create new Dataframe with empty/null field values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32067467/create-new-dataframe-with-empty-null-field-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried this and it works.

```
df = df.withColumn("c", functions.lit(null.asInstanceOf[String]).cast(StringType))
```

Sorry, it should be cast... I've modified it.